# Grouped select-all implementation with vue

Tags: vue.js

In this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q50yrsbh/1/), I want to implement that when all sub checkbox are chosen, the closest parent checkbox to be chosen. When choose the parent checkbox, all its sub checkbox to be chosen.

In this scene, I init all the sub checkbox status with `false` and and bind sub checkbox, while the parent checkbox's model is bind with `computed` property. In my option, this case is just a `computed` scene, no need of `watch` or `methods`.

But when I try to write my code, I find that the `set` function does nothing when I selected the parent checkbox. And I check the docs, some demos and find nothing about how to realize the `grouped select-all` case.

*ps: The menus' key length is dynamic.*

Hope that I have explain my problem clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind parent checkbox with a computed property, so that it will become true if all children's checkboxes are true.

And add an event handler on change for the parent checkbox, whenever it changes, the state of childrens states change also.

Comment: Event handler can solve but I think the best way is `computed`.